# Hive query to dump all tables into one

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have multiple `Databases` in `Hive`. `A, B, C`.

Database A has hive tables `One, Two, Three.` All three tables have `different schemas`.

How can I write a hive script to dump data of all three tables into a `single csv file.`

Comment: It's no different than exporting a single table to CSV, except you do it three times.  But why would you want tables with different schemas in a single CSV?

Comment: @Andrew But How would I loop through all the tables at once without explicitly stating each table.

Comment: You can do it using shell script.

Comment: @ManishSaraf In shell script I am not able to change the database. when I use hive -e 'use A'. it doesnt work.

Comment: You have to specify the table names somewhere, in your hive script or your shell script.

Comment: Not clear. If `"Database A has hive tables One, Two, Three."` why do we care about the existent of databases `B` and `C`?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz There are othere tables inside B and C. I will use similar query used for A to get data from B and C as well.

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly. What about @Andrew question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
#!/bin/bash
for db in A B C #List of databases
do
  tbs=$(hive -S -e "use $db; show tables")
  for tb in $tbs
  do
    hive -e "set hive.cli.print.header=true; use $db; SELECT * FROM $tb;" | sed 's/[\t]/,/g' >> sampleData.csv
  done
done
```

Comment: Would it dump data of all db's into a single csv ?

Comment: Same comment as before - Why not using Beeline where you can explicitly choose the output format instead of counting on the uncontrolled output of the hive CLI?